# how do l hold a lot of same information from api in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with react, if I fetch the same information from an API and that information is repeated, I have to create a lot of variables to hold every single one of the information.

So I repeat like const img1 and const img2 and three to hold all that l want from the same thing l just repeat it. How can l do it better?

```
setDisplayName(response.data.feed["0"].display.displayName);

setIngSteps(response.data.feed["0"].content.preparationSteps);

setImg(response.data.feed["0"].display.images["0"]);

setDisplayName2(response.data.feed["1"].display.displayName)

setIngSteps2(response.data.feed["1"].content.preparationSteps);

setImg2(response.data.feed["1"].display.images["0"]);

setDisplayName3(response.data.feed["1"].display.displayName)

setIngSteps3(response.data.feed["1"].content.preparationSteps);

setImg3(response.data.feed["1"].display.images["0"]);
```

Is there another simpler way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no rule that says a state value needs to be a *single value*.  Any object can be stored in state.

So just store the object in state:

```
setData(response.data);
```

Then you can *retrieve* the values from that state object as needed.